# Why am I getting a UrlGenerationError with missing required keys [:id]?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a link to the `show` action for my nested-resource `product`.

I have read other answers and it seems the accepted solution is to do something like

```
<%= link_to 'Product Page', category_product_path(product) %>
```

I am doing this and still getting the same error. I will post the error and the relevant code below. I would appreciate any and all feedback.

The full error message given by the browser

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Categories#show
No route matches {:action=>"show", :category_category_name=>#<Product id: 2, product_name: "Steak", product_description: "Pack of steaks", product_price: 19, category_id: 2, created_at: "2019-01-07 22:18:26", updated_at: "2019-01-07 22:18:26">, :category_name=>"Meat", :controller=>"products"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

From the view:

```
<%= render @category.products %>
```

From the partial:

```
<%= link_to 'Product page', category_product_path(product) %>
```

from 'rails routes':
[relevant routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n4oJ.png)

I am trying to render all products for the product's category in a table, and I am having trouble getting the link right. I would appreciate any help.

EDIT:
I found a solution by changing the link to

```
<%= link_to 'Product Page', [@category, product] %>
```

I feel like this is not the most rails way though, if somebody knows a better way I would love to know it.

Comment: Did you notice ? missing required key `:id`

Comment: No `:id` in your url params and whole product object is in `category_category_name` .

Comment: I found a solution that works by doing '<%= link_to "Page", [@category, product] %>' I feel like this isn't the most rails way though

Comment: Move `<%= link_to 'Product page', category_product_path(product) %>` to the view and check if it works there. Let us know.

Comment: That line is in a partial view that is being rendered in the view. I tried moving it to the view but no luck. Got it working with '<%= link_to 'Product page', [@category, product] %>'